# Using flexbox gap with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, next.js, styled-components

I want to use flexbox's new gap property in my `Next.js` app using `styled-components` without losing support for example Safari.
I found this polyfill https://www.npmjs.com/package/flex-gap-polyfill But I'm having trouble figuring out where and if at all it fits. If I've understood correctly, Next supports using `PostCSS` but `styled-components` does not? How do I make the polyfill linked above work with these two components?

Example of the code I'd like to write and have supported on modern platforms:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
gap: 16px;
```

The code I found to be able to use `styled-components` with `Next`. The file is `_document.js`

```
import Document from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  try {
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
          sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
      });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: (
        <>
          {initialProps.styles}
          {sheet.getStyleElement()}
        </>
      ),
    };
  } finally {
    sheet.seal();
  }
}
```

This is my postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {},
    "flex-gap-polyfill": {},
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": {},
    "postcss-preset-env": {
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: "no-2009",
      },
      stage: 3,
      features: {
        "custom-properties": false,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Yes NextJS supports styled-components and the code for the _document.js file to setup the library for SSR is correct. But I do not understand what your actual question is

Comment: @tobzilla90 I've edited for clarity, but my question is basically: How do I use the linked polyfill with styled-components and next.js

Comment: I have not used polyfills and PostCSS myself but Next JS has a page in the docs about PostCSS https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config and also an example project on their github page https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples

Comment: @tobzilla90 I've looked into that and attempted adding the plugin like they describe, but it did do anything.

Comment: Were you able to resolve that at the end and use the package? Or did you end up with another solution? Just ran into the same issue as you did :')